# NodeJS - How to get remote IP Address

Tags: node.js, ip, real-time

For my project, I need to fetch the remote IP address of another NodeJS Server.
In fact, in many countries such as Belgium, the IP address of a computer provided by the telecom is not a fixed IP and can change every xx hours.

I need to know how I can get the Internet IP address of a remote NodeJs computer in real-time.

Example: an internet provider change the IP of a nodeJS computer: I want to know in "relative" real-time the new IP.

Thanks to much,
visualight

Comment: In fact, the nodeJS server are hosted on private ip address on many company. for my backend i need to know the current ip address if it change. Thanks

Comment: I suspect you'd like to access the remote NodeJS server (currently by IP) from a (NodeJS) client and since the IP changes you need to determine the new IP every XX hours? You might think about connecting via hostname and using a [DynDNS service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyn_%28company%29) of your choice?

Comment: Is it possible to make my own dyndns service with nodejs ?

Comment: Technically, yes. But you need a central server whose IP does not change (some hosting provider, cloud service), so that the server may push the new IP to or the client may fetch it from that server. -- Can you please clarifiy your question to reflect these details and state if you accept central servers (like the DynDNS approach or your own NodeJS cloude service)? (My first comment was mainly a request for clarification with some hint.)

Comment: Yes i have a central nodejs server hosted in amazon cloud (static ip). Each client is connected to this server. How i can send in real time the new ip address of my clients to the static server? Thanks

Comment: Please specify "realtime" (how many secods may pass between re-dialin and IP update). Beside that I suspect a X/Y problem here: what do you want to do with the always-uptodate-IP? Will the (cloud) server try to connect to the clients, will all adresses tracked by the server sent to other clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the remote server you want to communicate with switches its ip address and doesn't tell you (as in, contacts your server in some way), you are basically out of luck.

If there is a domain pointing to the other machine, you could use this snippet (which I shamelessly copied from the [official docs](http://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns)) to force a DNS resolve:

```
var dns = require('dns');

dns.resolve4('www.google.com', function (err, addresses) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('addresses: ' + JSON.stringify(addresses));

  addresses.forEach(function (a) {
    dns.reverse(a, function (err, domains) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }

      console.log('reverse for ' + a + ': ' + JSON.stringify(domains));
    });
  });
});
```

**UPDATE:** There is [module on npm](https://github.com/alsotang/externalip) that allows you to get the public ip address of a machine. Its very simple, as it just does a request against curlmyip.com and returns the result. You could set up some polling interval using `setInterval` and send it to the other nodes whenever you detect a change.

Comment: Yes i am out of luck but i think you not understand the deal. In fact : i have a server with a static ip address who have nodejs installed with a app. My clients have also a nodejs server installer with a front-end connected to my server. So, when the IP change, how i can send the new ip adress to the server lke : $(ip).on('change'), function() ... ??